# How to reverse geocode serverside with python, json and google maps?

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

I'm trying serverside reverse geocoding that can get me a json response and now I want to get 2 or 3 variables from the json response:

I'd like to parse for instance this data and end with eg.
`administrative_area_level_1 = 'Stockholm'`

`jsondata = json.load(urllib2.urlopen('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=59.3,18.1&sensor=false'))`

Here is my python code that fetches the json, now I wonder how to parse it to get just the

- administrative_area_level_1 long_name (ie state or region name)
- locality long name (ie city name)
- an understanding how to parse my json

I can parse it but it is not always is comes out as administrative_area_1:

`jsondata["results"][0]["address_components"][5]["long_name"]`

The line above correctly outputs "New York" for a point in New York but for Stockholm it outputs a postal city ie Johanneshow which is not the administraive_area_1 (region/state). So how guarantee that the function always returns the administrative_area_1, preferably without looping?

I want it to work something like the following with direct access to country, region and city:

```
logging.info("country:"+str(jsondata["results"][9]["formatted_address"]))
logging.info("administrative_area_level_1:"+str(jsondata["results"][8]["formatted_address"]))
logging.info("locality:"+str(jsondata["results"][8]["formatted_address"]))
```

Thanks in advance

Update

It's a good answer here with the results I expected. While waiting for the answer I also tried implement a solution myself that seems to do it:

```
jsondata = json.load(urllib2.urlopen('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+str(ad.geopt.lat)+','+str(ad.geopt.lon)+'&sensor=false'))
logging.info("geography:"+str(jsondata["results"][1]["formatted_address"]))
region = None
city = None
for result in jsondata["results"]:
  #logging.info("result:"+str(result))
  for component in result["address_components"]:
    logging.info("components:"+str(component))
    logging.info("components type:"+str(component["types"]))
    if 'administrative_area_level_1' in component["types"]:
      #logging.info(unicode('found admin area:%s' % component["long_name"]))
      region = component["long_name"]
    if 'locality' in component["types"]:
      logging.info("found locality:"+str(component["long_name"]))
      city = component["long_name"]
```

---

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Processing the response

There is **no need to parse the JSON** - it is already parsed by `json.load()` and returned as Python's data structure. **Use it like simple dictionary** with lists or different dictionaries in it.

### Accessing the needed part of the response

To access data you should be working with you can use the following:

```
jsondata['results'][0]['address_components']
```

which is where all **information on geographical names** is included:

> [{u'long_name': u'S\xf6dra L\xe4nken', u'types': [u'route'], u'short_name': u'S\xf6dra L\xe4nken'}, {u'long_name': u'Stockholm', u'types': [u'locality', u'political'], u'short_name': u'Stockholm'}, {u'long_name': u'Stockholm', u'types': [u'administrative_area_level_1', u'political'], u'short_name': u'Stockholm'}, {u'long_name': u'Sweden', u'types': [u'country', u'political'], u'short_name': u'SE'}, {u'long_name': u'12146', u'types': [u'postal_code'], u'short_name': u'12146'}, {u'long_name': u'Johanneshov', u'types': [u'postal_town'], u'short_name': u'Johanneshov'}]

### Filtering data you need

As you can see, there is plenty of data you do not need, but you want only `locality` and `administrative_area_level_1` information. You can filter the data using `filter()` Python function like that:

```
>>> mydata = jsondata['results'][0]['address_components']
>>> types = ['locality', 'administrative_area_level_1']
>>> geonames = filter(lambda x: len(set(x['types']).intersection(types)), mydata)
```

Basically you are getting only elements that have 'locality' or 'administrative_area_level_1' in their "types" lists. After the above, `geonames` will be list containing dictionaries you need:

> [{u'long_name': u'Stockholm', u'types': [u'locality', u'political'], u'short_name': u'Stockholm'}, {u'long_name': u'Stockholm', u'types': [u'administrative_area_level_1', u'political'], u'short_name': u'Stockholm'}]

### Displaying the data

To display their names you can eg. iterate through them, displaying `long_name`s and respective `types` values:

```
>>> for geoname in geonames:
    common_types = set(geoname['types']).intersection(set(types))
    print '{} ({})'.format(geoname['long_name'], str(', '.join(common_types)))


Stockholm (locality)
Stockholm (administrative_area_level_1)
```

Is this what you expected?

### Whole code

The code could look like this:

```
import json
import urllib2

def get_geonames(lat, lng, types):
    url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json' + \
            '?latlng={},{}&sensor=false'.format(lat, lng)
    jsondata = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
    address_comps = jsondata['results'][0]['address_components']
    filter_method = lambda x: len(set(x['types']).intersection(types))
    return filter(filter_method, address_comps)

lat, lng = 59.3, 18.1
types = ['locality', 'administrative_area_level_1']

# Display all geographical names along with their types
for geoname in get_geonames(lat, lng, types):
    common_types = set(geoname['types']).intersection(set(types))
    print '{} ({})'.format(geoname['long_name'], ', '.join(common_types))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! In the meantime I also developed a solution that filters the locality and the admin area level 1 so we can compare the 2 solutions. I'm updating the question with my "solution" and I will also try the one from this answer. What I basically did was looping through results and looping through types to find matches and then assign those matches to variables region and city. Thank you!

Comment: @Nickle: Your solution should work also! :) The thing is I focused on readability, length and reusability of my code - it uses `filter()` instead of big loop, `lambda` instead of conditional checks, formatting instead of concatenation. The last one (string formatting) could improve the readability of your code a lot. But as I said, it should work :)